# How to combine listed and horizontal table notes

Tags: threeparttable, threeparttablex, tnote, tnotex

I have the following table:

How can I put the * notes horizontally and keep the notes 1 and 2 listed vertically

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    bookmarksnumbered,
    citecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarksopen=true}
\usepackage[
top=2.5cm,
left=2.5cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item[*] Experiment 1
\item[**] Experiment 2
\item[1] \label{tn1} First table note
\item[2] \label{tn2} Second table note
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\toprule
Text\tnotex{tn1}&Text\tnotex{tn1} \tnote{,} \tnote{*}\\
Text\tnotex{tn1} \tnote{,} \tnote{**}&Text\tnotex{tn2}\\
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution.

Add option `para` to `TableNotes` to make the notes come one-after-another without line breaks. And then add line breaks manually.

Eventually, the codes (only modified parts) are as follows.

```
\begin{TableNotes}[para]
\item[*] Experiment 1
\item[**] Experiment 2\\
\item[1] \label{tn1} First table note\\
\item[2] \label{tn2} Second table note
\end{TableNotes}
```

Comment: works perfectly